# Java GregorianCalendar lightweight

Tags: java, gregorian-calendar

Is the `java.util.GregorianCalendar` a lightweight object? In other words, does calling the constructor in a web application setting with each request extract nothing more than a trivial performance penalty, or does it pay to cache a copy of the object for shared use by the application?

Answer (score 5):

You can improve the performance of GregoianCalendar by caching/sharing the `TimeZone` and `Locale` which are immutable.

> Is the java GregorianCalendar a lightweight object?

If by lightweight you mean; like a balloon made of concrete. ;)

> does calling the constructor in a web application setting with each request extract nothing more than a trivial performance penalty

Its can be relatively trivial compared to everything else you are doing.  You can't know until you cpu profile the application.

> does it pay to cache a copy of the object for shared use by the application

Only if you treat the objects as immutable (which may not be very useful)

Using a shared mutable GregorianCalendar could introduce bugs which are far worse than running a little bit slow.

BTW: I would consider using JodaTime. It is slight faster but generally better to use.

Answer (score 1):

Use [JODA datetime](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/). It is added in also java 8.

Comment: It will not be added exactly like it is now in Java 8; however, there's going to be a [new date and time API](http://threeten.sourceforge.net) which is going to look a lot like Joda Time.

Comment: FYI, the [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project is now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), with the team advising migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes. See [Tutorial by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).

Answer (score 1):

## java.time

The modern approach uses the *java.time* classes built into Java 8 and later. Avoid the troublesome legacy classes wherever possible.

Instead of `GregorianCalendar`, use `ZonedDateTime`.

### Converting between legacy and modern

You can even convert, for inter-operating with old code. Call new methods added to the old classes.

```
ZonedDateTime zdt = myGregCal.toZonedDateTime() ;      // From legacy to modern.
GregorianCalendar gc = GregorianCalendar.from( zdt ) ; // From modern to legacy.
```

### Thread-safety

One big problem with caching a `GregorianCalendar` object is that it is not [thread-safe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread_safety). By keep it around, you may generate exceptions or bad data at runtime by making unsafe calls.

In contrast, java.time uses [immutable object](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immutable_object). Instead of modifying some aspect of an existing object, a new object is generated instead. The java.time classes are designed to be thread-safe.

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the java.time classes.
  - For earlier Android, the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts *ThreeTen-Backport* (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).